# How can I customize the animation for the titleView?

Tags: ios, animation, uikit, uinavigationbar, titleview

In my UINavigationController I have set the titleView of a viewcontrollers `NavigationItem`. Now I want to add a custom animation to this, how can I do this?

If you want to post an example, I want to animate the title up and fade it out when it disappears and for the appear animation, I want the title to animate down and fade in.

Comment: Can you post some code of what you've tried thus far?

Comment: I'm sorry, I haven't tried anything, as I don't really know where to start.